# Any way to differentiate a lead as being imported?

Tags: data-import-wizard

Is there a way to know if a lead was created in an import process vs other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are records that have already been imported, field "Lead Source" or possibly "Lead Record Type" might have information that tells you this.  You could also fall back on using field "Created by" or "Created Date" to locate the imported records.

If these are records to be imported, you can add a field to the Lead object (or possibly add a item to "Lead Source" if that fits how you use the field).

Comment: I'll use the Lead Source